# stm32 HAL library eclipse

Tags: eclipse, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I´m using Eclipse IDE with ARM plugin to develop a project on my F4-Discovery. I created an empty template project and started to use functions from stm32 HAL libraries and I got error like:

> undefined reference to `HAL_DMA_Init'
>
> undefined reference to `HAL_UART_Init'

Necessary .c and .h files are in the right directories, but Eclipse recognised only half of .c files and the others scratched out. [This image explains my problem.](http://s8.postimg.org/9v8v24n5h/stm32.png) What´s wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an include path to Eclipse CDT.  Assuming this is a managed build (as opposed to using an external Makefile), you need to follow the directions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm).

> **Adding Include paths and symbols in Managed Build System**
>
> For CDT projects, you can define include paths and preprocessor
>   symbols for the parser. This lets the parser understand the contents
>   of the C/C++ source code so that you can more effectively use the
>   search and code completion features.
>
> If Autodiscovery is enabled, after a build finishes, any discovered
>   paths and symbols will be displayed in the Discovered Paths section.
>   You can also define the properties on a per project basis in the C/C++
>   Projects or Navigator views.
>
> **To add include paths and symbols:**
>
> To set properties for your project, right-click your CDT project and select Properties. Alternatively, to set properties for a specific
>   source file in your project, right-click a source file within your
>   make project and select Properties.
>
> 1. Expand C/C++ General and select Paths and Symbols.
> 2. Click here to see an illustration (displayed in a separate window).
> 3. Click Add to define new element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
> 4. Click Edit to change selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
> 5. Click Delete to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc).
> 6. Click Export to make selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) exported.
> 7. Click Unexport to remove selected element (Include Path, Symbol, Library path etc) from export list.
> 8. Click Move up and Move down to set elements (Include Paths, Library paths etc) order.

Answer (score 0):

In properties (Alt+Enter) of file you need, tick off the checkbox says "Exclude resource from build". [as shown in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfywv.png)

Answer (score 0):

"Undefined reference" is likely a linker error. You're not compiling the actual source code of the library you're trying to use.

Go to `system > src > stm32f4-hal` then right click the library file you're trying to include. Uncheck "exclude from build."